# ImportError: No module named requests but module already exists

Tags: python, python-requests, python-module

My code fails when it tries to import requests, despite it already being installed. I did a *pip list* and saw the module requested there, I uninstalled it and reinstalled it with both *pip install* and *pip3 install*, also added sudo both times. Whenever I try to install it I get the message that the requirement is already satisfied. Is there something else that I could try?
If it helps I am using VSCode on a Mac, I also have Jupyter and Spyder installed and have used them before however I’ve never used the requests module on this device.

**UPDATE:**

I created a virtualenv and installed requests there, when running the script in the venv I am not getting the error anymore, however I am still curious why it was being thrown on the base env, anything else I could check?

Comment: Are you in the correct environment ...i mean the environment in which you have installed requests

Comment: I guess I should be, on the command line I see (base), and I haven't created any venv so using the base environment of the PC to install the module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have multiple installations/environments.

Before the "import requests", line put "import sys; print(sys.executable)".
This prints the python executable being used - verify that it is the same one that  you can successfully import requests with .

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have ran the code and this is what I got:

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

So I am using Python 2.7 then, right? So pip install should have worked?

Comment: If you run python from the terminal directly, does "import requests" work? If so, if you run "import sys; print(sys.executable)", do you get the same python executable path that you pasted in the comment?

Comment: No, still getting the same error when running it from the terminal, the executable is just the same. That being said, I created a venv and it all worked fine from there, although the sys.executable there was a different one as it was pointing to the venv

Comment: Yes, a virtual env will have a different executable then outside of it, and probably has a fresh requests install in it. So if you activate your virtual environment and try to run your script the intended way, is everything working now? If you want to fix your requests module outside your virtual environment, you might need to uninstall it and reinstall it or install it with the --upgrade argument.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was deleting three folders having names starting with "request-SOMETHING" in the directory that pip3 specifies when you try to install requests again, e.g.

```
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

Then just reinstall with pip and it should be in your sys.executable directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
pip install chardet2 urllib3
```

or

```
python3 -m pip install requests
```

There is a problem with package dependency

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried both commands and still getting the same error :(